# Algo - key-values expression to parse (C)

Tags: c, regex, json, parsing

I'm working on a way to write in a string key-values data like this :

```
{k1=v1__k2=v2__k3=v3}
```

Not a big deal to parse, but the problem became bigger when I wanted to add the possibility to write a set of key-values as a value of a key, like this :

```
{k1=v1__k2={k21=v21__k22=v22}__k3=v3}
```

Also, it would be better to enable the possibility to add more depth in my structure, example:

```
{k1=v1__k2=v2__k3={k31={k311=v311__k312=v312__k313={k3131=v3131}}__k32=v32}
```

I tried (in C) to parse it, but it becomes harder to parse it in a simple way (split __ and {} characters) and I also tried regex to split each key and value but I lose the hierarchy (depth) data...

Constraints of the problem:

- Data structure can accept more than one depth
- special characters (or set of characters) can be changed (different from __ or {})

Anyone knows a good algorithm?
I'm not sure, but JSon format has the same constraints, am I wrong?
Many thank @ll

Comment: The easiest would be to use recursion. And don't even think about regular expressions.

Comment: Ok but how do you parse the 'value' to take the whole value and not only a sub value ?
Example: {k=v__k={k=v__k=v__k={k=v}}__k={k=v}__k=v}
You need to count opening and ending of set? I will try

Comment: You usually parse this kind of stuff by creating an appropriate data structure. E. g., a dynamic array of key-value pairs (something like `struct dict { char **keys; union { char *str; struct dict *dict; } *values; }`. Then you can have the parser build a tree (called the AST, for "abstract syntax tree") of this data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than attempt to write you own data representation, I suggest you use either XML or JSON. Both are more than up to the job. If you are using XML, `libxml` is your friend. There are many many JSON libraries, including (for example), `libyajl`. Both XML and JSON are tried and tested, cope with escaping and so fort. XML also allows querying with `xpath` and (if you want it) DTD functionality. Believe me, this is better than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I think you are right, I will use some json libraries. My choice goes to jsmn, I'll try it.